# Convert raw hyperlink into img

Tags: php

```
       <div class="listing_element info_pro">
        <p class="pro_title">Country</p>
        <div class="sub_text text_small pro_text"><?php echo countryFlag($user['country']); ?></div>

    </div>
```

with the above code I was trying to add Country flag into a profile page, I have succeeded somehow but the code shows the path of the flag. I want to have it shown as an image.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo... ?>" />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<img>` tag with `src`

```
<div class="sub_text text_small pro_text"><img src="<?php echo countryFlag($user['country']); ?>" height="50" width="50"></div>
```